# How do you output commas from a csv file

Tags: vb.net

I have created a program in visual studio 2010 which a user can input a sentence and then it will split the positions of the words and where they occur and the words. It then outputs them to two separate csv files.

If the user presses another button, it will regenerate the original inputted sentence.

Its seems to work with all types of punctuation apart from commas as they are the separator for csv files.

Is there a way of making the program output commas as well as other types of punctuation?

**How i output to a CSV file:**

```
 Dim mydocpath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
    Using WordStore As System.IO.TextWriter = System.IO.File.CreateText(mydocpath + "\Output\Words.csv")

        Using IndexStore As System.IO.TextWriter = System.IO.File.CreateText(mydocpath + "\Output\Outputs.csv")
```

**How I read from a CSV file:**

```
   Using CSVFileToRead As New FileIO.TextFieldParser(mydocpath + "\Output\Outputs.csv")
```

**The current problem involving commas:**

```
 Dim output As String = Nothing
            For Each Word As String In UserInput.Split(CChar(" "))
                output &= (words.IndexOf(Word) + 1).ToString & ", "
            Next
            Label1.Text = output.Substring(0, output.Length - 2)
```

Comment: Instead of describing what you do, please post a bit of code and show us how you do :) Especially how you create and fill the CSV file.

Comment: Set the [Delimiters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.delimiters(v=vs.110).aspx) property of `CSVFileToRead` to a value which is not used by your users, e.g. a pipe `|` or similar.

Comment: [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cakac7e6(v=vs.110).aspx) is an example for reading a csv file.

Comment: you can escape csv data with quotes: `"row1","row2","row3 with ""escaped quotes"""`  Double quotes in the data are escaped with another double quote.